# Multiplos spinners

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Estou criando uma app na qual tenho um `TableLayout`, no qual vou adicionando `TableRow` dinamicamente com `Spinners` e `TextEdit`.

É possível criar um `EventHandler` comum para todos os `Spinners`?

Comment: Mesmo sendo para WinForms, veja esse post da Microsoft. [Como conectar vários eventos a um único manipulador de eventos no Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/3exstx90(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas você pode atribuir os eventos de vários objetos à mesma função:

```
FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.Spn1).Click += EventoClick_Click;
FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.Spn2).Click += EventoClick_Click;

private void EventoClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Aqui você pode manipular o objeto que chamou o evento usando o sender           
}
```

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo.